# Deploying and publishing my first asp.net mvc 3 web application

Tags: sql-server-2008, small-business, deployment, asp.net-mvc

I want to deploy and publish my first asp.net mvc 3 web application at my client side (the client is a  small office with 2-4 employees that need to access the application) , currently i finished developing my web application using the **free Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 express and the free SQL Server 2008 R2 Express database** .
So my concerns are :-
***1. The free sql express database that i am currently using have a limitation of 10 GB i think***
So i want to buy SQL server for small business to remove the database limitations.
So my questions that i need help with them are:-

****1.  If i use the sql server for small business then will my web application have other limitations on production i am unaware of ?**

**2.    Will be using SQL server for small business my right choice? baring in my that the system will be used by 2-4 clients only?**

**3.    How much does “approximate ” the sql server database will cost in US dollars?**

**4.    Are there any other software that i need to buy to be able to deploy and publish the application  on intranet and the internet ?****

Appreciate any help 
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Can you still buy SQL Server 2008 for Small Business?  You need Windows Essential Server & MS has canned that product line, you might want to check that out. In addition [2012 has just been released](http://tinyurl.com/7jhhbr8), usually the trend goes even if you want to run an old edition, you'll need to buy the license for the latest version. The paid for licenses usually mean you can run with more cores & with more RAM.  The enterprise edition has lots of big database features like partitioning, online index rebuilds ect.  I dont think this is stuff you will miss in standard or even the express edition.  [Look here for a full features comparison between editions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)  Express has the most limitations, personally, I'd stick with that till it becomes an issue, from there you can upgrade, which is a simple process.
2. If you really want to get away from express edition a workgroup edition i.e. server + CAL (Client Access License) will probably suit your needs best.  When you buy this edition it comes with 5 CALs.
3. Prices for 2008R2 were about $1,800 (cannot find out what it will cost for 2012, but its been reported as not a significant change from 2008R2). Additional CALs for 2012 are being priced at $209 per user.  Prices are different for Volume Licensing & also different if your buying the license from a hosting provider (i.e. SPLA) If your ready to make the investment, best to speak to a friendly reseller.
4. Other software to deploy asp.net MVC?  IIS 7/7.5 which comes on Windows Server 2008/R2 is essential, or is that stating the obvious?  If it's an intranet app, then maybe having Active Directory (i.e. a Windows domain) to setup will help you do things like integrated authentication. Avoid express, even vista/windows 7 will run iis 7 http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/28/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, i think my best choice will be is to publish my application using the sql server express and IIS 7 express which are all free as my client is small and the database size might not exceed 10 GB within the first three years or even more. After that if the database size became an issue i can upgrade to the standard edition. what do u think ? Best Regards

Comment: AFAIK iis express will not run as a service, or on port 80. its not designed for a production scenario, no matter how small

Comment: Even if the application will be deplyed only on the intranet? . i already deploy my asp.net mvc3 on my machine under IIS 7.5 express without any problems, but will the other users be unable to connect to the application ?

Comment: Just because you can do it doesn't mean you should. I wouldn't do it. Spend the extra 5 minutes & get the proper version of IIS installed

Answer (score 0):

1. We don't know what you know, so no way to answer that.
2. Define "right choice". Sounds reasonable, but see #1.
3. Depends on how you buy; there are literally a dozen different ways to buy the same edition, and there are several different editions, and they all have different prices, and there are qualifications for some of those buying options and editions. Contact a reseller to figure out which is best for you.
4. Depends on exactly what you're app does, see #1.